# 16-bit FizzBuzz in x86 NASM assembly

Tags: assembly, fizzbuzz

Since this problem involves small numbers (particularly with a small loop count of 100), it's possible to ease the modulo operation setup by simply working with 16-bit and 8-bit registers:

$$\dfrac{\text{[AX] (16-bit register)}}{\text{[other 8-bit register]}} = \text{[AH] (remainder)}$$

My main concern is with the layout.  Every "basic" high-level implementation I've seen has a check and print together for each case.  I've found it easier to do the same thing here, but I'm not sure if that would also be too readable in assembly.

I'm also aware that it's good to minimize register-moving.  Unfortunately, I still do that with every case since I'm incrementing with one register (`CX`) and using another (`AX`) for the dividend.  I *can* stick to `AX` for both, but that may involve keeping a copy of the current counter value, which may just make the code a bit more complicated.  I suppose it's not much of a problem here anyway.

Macros used:

- `nwln` -  prints a newline
- `PutStr` - prints a defined string
- `PutInt` - prints a 16-bit integer value

It's not necessary to address the macros; they do work properly.

```
%include "macros.s"

.DATA

fizz_lbl:       DB    "Fizz", 0
buzz_lbl:       DB    "Buzz", 0
fizzbuzz_lbl:   DB    "FizzBuzz", 0

.CODE
.STARTUP

xor   CX, CX ; counter

main_loop:
   inc   CX
   cmp   CX, 100

   jg    done

   fizzbuzz_check:
      mov   AX, CX ; dividend = counter
      mov   BH, 15 ; divisor
      div   BH     ; (counter / 15)

      cmp   AH, 0            ; counter divisible by 15?
      je    print_fizzbuzz   ; if so, proceed with printing

      jmp   fizz_check       ; if not, try checking for fizz

      print_fizzbuzz:
          PutStr   fizzbuzz_lbl
          nwln
          jmp      main_loop

   fizz_check:
      mov   AX, CX ; dividend = counter
      mov   BH, 3  ; divisor
      div   BH     ; (counter / 3)

      cmp   AH, 0        ; counter divisible by 3?
      je    print_fizz   ; if so, proceed with printing

      jmp   buzz_check   ; if not, try checking for buzz

      print_fizz:
          PutStr   fizz_lbl
          nwln
          jmp      main_loop

   buzz_check:
      mov   AX, CX ; dividend = counter
      mov   BH, 5  ; divisor
      div   BH     ; (counter / 5)

      cmp   AH, 0        ; counter divisible by 5?
      je    print_buzz   ; if so, proceed with printing

      jmp   print_other  ; if not, then can only display number

      print_buzz:
          PutStr   buzz_lbl
          nwln
          jmp      main_loop

   print_other:
      PutInt   CX
      nwln
      jmp   main_loop

done:
   .EXIT
```

Comment: Nice! +1 for the effort writing this is a low level language. May I suggest posting the result set?

Comment: @Phrancis: For verification of successful execution, you mean?

Comment: Yeah basically. Though I don't doubt it did exec.

Comment: @Phrancis: I only hesitate because it'll take up a lot (possibly unnecessary) room.  Would a link to a screenshot suffice?

Comment: Where can we obtain `macros.s`?

Comment: @200_success: It was provided to me by a college, and it's not available online.  I just have it on my hard drive.

Comment: @Jamal may not be a big deal if it's a PITA :)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Since we're doing this in assembly language, it makes sense to do it much more efficiently than is typically done in high level languages.  Otherwise, why bother with assembly language? So with that said, there are ways that this can be made much, much more efficient.

### Avoid division

The `div` instruction in x86 is one of the slower instructions possible.  Since we already know that we're looking for numbers divisible by 3, 5 or both, what would make far more sense is to simple keep countdown counters for both.  Your initialization currently says:

```
    xor cx, cx
```

It could be easily expanded to say:

```
    xor cx, cx
    mov bx, 0503h  ; set bh = 5 counter, bl = 3 counter
```

Then instead of dividing, simply decrement:

```
    inc cx
    cmp cx, 100
    jg done
;  instead of this...
;    dec bh
;    dec bl
;    cmp bx, 0
; per suggestion from @Chris Jester-Young use this:
    sub bx, 0101h
    je print_fizzbuzz
    test bl, bl
    je print_fizz
    test bh, bh
    je print_buzz
print_other:
```

Naturally the various `print_...` routines would have to reset `bh`, `bl` or both as well as printing.

### Improve formatting

Generally speaking, assembly language code is not indented in the way you have your code indented.  It's much more linear, with the only indentation for assembly language statements or directives.

### Consider better I/O

Your output routines are not shown, but it's likely that it would be more efficient to keep the numeric output in string form, incrementing each ASCII digit and emitting the string, rather than repeatedly converting from binary register contents to a string value.

Comment: Instead of `dec bh; dec bl`, you can just use `sub bx, 101h`. Then you can directly `jz print_fizzbuzz` without a `cmp`. The other comparisons can use `test bl, bl` and `test bh, bh`, to eliminate the literal 0s in the code (this makes the code smaller).

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young All excellent suggestions.  Thanks!

Comment: Interesting hack to use partial registers for this, especially in a way that avoids reading a wider register after writing one of its halves (except when you reset only one of the counters).  That would cause a partial-register stall on P6-family.  ([Why doesn't GCC use partial registers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41573502)).    Another option is to unroll by 3 and only use one down-counter, like I played around with in [this FizzBuzz answer](//stackoverflow.com/questions/28334034/fizzbuzz-in-assembly-segmentation-fault/37494090#37494090) where I stored bytes into a buffer for one print.

Comment: `test reg,reg` is preferred over `cmp reg,0` - it's 1 byte shorter and sets FLAGS exactly equivalently in all cases (except for AF).  [Test whether a register is zero with CMP reg,0 vs OR reg,reg?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33724806)

Answer (score 7):

## Use local labels

All of your labels are global labels.

Since all these labels are trying to complete the same task and they all work together, they should all be grouped under a single global variable, and have the rest of the labels be local.

For example, you would change this label:

```
fizzbuzz_check:
```

to:

```
.fizzbuzz_check:
```

Also, it's just better practice.

---

## Different conditional jump

At the end of each check for either Fizz, Buzz, or FizzBuzz, you do something like this:

```
  je    print_fizzbuzz   ; if so, proceed with printing

  jmp   fizz_check       ; if not, try checking for fizz

  print_fizzbuzz:
```

This could be shortened to:

```
  jne    main_loop

  print_fizzbuzz:
```

If the `jne` doesn't pass, execution will fall through to `print_fizzbuzz`

---

## Versatility

Right now, your code only supports Fizz, Buzz, and Fizzbuzz.

But what if you wanted to change things up a bit? Say you wanted to say "Fizz" every fourth number?

To do this, you'd be adding quite a chunk of code.

Although, there is an easier way to do this; use `struc`s.

Say you created this `struc`:

```
struc message

    .say: resb 10
    .num: resb 1

endstruc
```

You could then do something create a bunch of messages easily like this:

```
messages:
    db "FizzBuzz", 0, 0
    db 15

    db "Buzz",0,0,0,0,0,0
    db 5

    db "Fizz",0,0,0,0,0,0
    db 3

    db 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0; so, when iterating, can know if the end has been reached
    db 0
```

(The extra 0's are for filling up the 10 bytes given for the name)
(Note the order: you want greatest to least)

And, you can easily

Now, in your main code, you can easily iterate through `messages` and, if the counter is evenly divisible by the value in the `num` field, then you log the `say` field.

Now, the code could be written like this:

```
xor cx, cx

main_loop:
    inc cx
    cmp cx, 100

    jg .done

    call search

    jmp main_loop

.done:
    .EXIT

search:
    mov si, messages

.next:
    mov ax, cx
    mov bh, [si + message.num]; divisor
    div bh

    cmp ah, 0; was evenly divisible
    je .print_message

    add si, message_size
    cmp byte [si], 0; the next item in `messages` is the terminator
    jne .next

    jmp .print_num

.print_message:
    PutStr [si + message.say]
    nwln
    ret
    
.print_num:
    PutInt cx
    nwln
    ret
```

*Note: This was troublesome to test out without `macros.s` so if there are any issues, notify me*

Comment: `messages:` \ `.fizzbuzz: db "FizzBuzz",0` \ `times 10 - ($ - .fizzbuzz) db 0` would be better for padding string fields to ten bytes long.

Comment: If you use `.num == 0` as the terminator, you only have to load it once per iter (load the first iteration's divisor ahead of the first iteration, i.e. rotate and partially peel the loop to make that happen).  Or with the current code, `div byte [si + message.num]` avoids wasting an instruction loading it into BH.  Also, you can put `.print_num` before `.print_message` so the loop can fall into it.  The main loop could also use a more efficient `do{cx++; }while(cx<100);` loop structure: [Why are loops always compiled into "do...while" style (tail jump)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47783926).

Comment: The code in `search` doesn't need to be a function, it could just be the loop body, even though it's large.  That could be less readable, but if you want to maximize readability, use a compiler.  Usually making code more general is the last thing you want to do when implementing in asm: take advantage of as many special cases as possible.  Again, otherwise use a compiler so it can take advantage of fixed constants on the fly (like 2 and 4 being powers of 2, it wouldn't use `div`), unless the code truly needs to handle runtime variable arrays of divisors and messages.